# how to set checkbox value false in datagridview one row

Tags: c#

how to set checkbox value false in datagridview one row

Comment: can you elaborate? Your question is not very clear. Do you want to create a combo box in a data grid cell?

Comment: Do you mean checkbox? What is false in a Combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void dgvTodaysPlan_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvTodaysPlan.CurrentCell is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            {
                dgvTodaysPlan.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }

        }
```

try this

Comment: but its not affecting until we change selection to other row

Answer (score 0):

// Add a new Column (ComboBox)

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colForeign = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); 
colForeign = MyDB.CreateComboBoxColumn("SELECT subjno,subject FROM subject", "ComboForeign", "subject", "subjno"); 
colForeign.HeaderText = "Subject"; 
colForeign.Width = 120; 
colForeign.DisplayStyle = 0; 
this.dataGridView2.Columns.Insert(3, colForeign) 
Use DataPropertyName to get the selected key column as in :- 
this.dataGridView2.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "subjno";
```

It appears that this would be much easier in VisualStudio - maybe??
And here is the routine to Create the Combobox Column - very messy compared with Delphi :-

```
public DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateComboBoxColumn(string strSQLSelect, string strColName, string strDisplay, string strValue) 
{ 
// Returns the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to be inserted 
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colComboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(); 
DataTable dtbElements = new DataTable(); 
MySqlDataAdapter dbaElements = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQLSelect, conn); 
// Set some parameters for the ComboBoxColumn 
colComboColumn.Name = strColName; 
colComboColumn.DisplayMember = strDisplay; 
colComboColumn.ValueMember = strValue; 
// Add the Elements 
dbaElements.Fill(dtbElements); 
colComboColumn.DataSource = dtbElements; 
// Return the column 
return colComboColumn; 
}
```

If the userAddedRow flag is set to true, unset the flag;
userAddedRow = false; and set id to 0, valid because autoincremented id's from server starting from 1 :-

```
dataGridView1["bookno", e.RowIndex].Value = 0;
```

Comment: sorry,i want set Checkbox value false in datagridview

Answer (score 0):

You should convert it into a `datagridviewcheckbox` and set its value to `false`.